# Can "network card can't connect to anything anymore" be solved without reboot?

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter, device-manager

I am sorry for the title, I'm not sure how to better put it in one snappy line.

I have a desktop PC with Intel Core i7-6700, Windows 10 Pro 64bit.

There is this sometimes (usually at very inconvenient occasions wrt. reboot) occuring phenomenon of that extra network card installed in my PC, "Intel(R) Gigabit CT Desktop Adapter", that while it usually works nicely, then on some day, after waking up Windows out of hibernation (not power save), I can't connect to anything (establish e.g. a SSH connection) that's physically connected to its network.

But all the LEDs on the attached switch's ports are on and it looks fine, IP configuration is as it should - only that the green LED on the network card's slot bracket itself is blinking in a steady 50:50 pulse pattern of ~ 2Hz, which looks unusual.
Power-cycling the switch didn't help.

The on-board network chip never has this problem. It's configured for DHCP.

The problematic extra card has a fixed IP and is connected to a ethernet switch with a bunch of local devices for development.

Now, when this happens, nothing seems to help, but restarting Windows.
De- and re-activating the network in the adapter settings does not help.

My attempt at deactivating the network card in the Device Manager resulted in the dev manager to freeze eternally (ok I waited only ~ 45min).
Is this a sign of there being an issue with the driver?

I can start another instance of the dev manager (while the 1st one hangs) that then will show the card (by icon) normally, but looking at properties reveals "no driver installed", and when I tell it to fetch the newest, it claims the best driver is already installed - so it seems to be in some corrupt in-between state due to the other devmgr instance not finihsing.

My question is: is there a known "generic" fix that solves a problem like that, which does not require rebooting the machine?
E.g. something that triggers some mechanism of Windows that tries more specific things (if it's a known category of problem), or a manual procedure of some sort. Can the driver be restarted somehow? I would have guessed that de/re-activating in devmgmt.msc would do that, not familiar with the architecture behind it - but no use if the thing freezes.

Btw, yes I allow Windows to install updated drivers etc. The computer/installation is about 1.5 years old. I hibernate/wakeup everyday, and this happens maybe once or twice a month, I would guess.

Comment: It sounds strange, but it might not actually be your network card that has a problem. It could be the router that manages your network that somehow blocks you. That said, it is weird that disabling and enabling the network interface does not fix the issue. Maybe you are enabling it too quickly. With a reboot, it often takes longer before the network card is enabled again. But if a reboot fixes it while disablign and enabling the card does not, it can be various things, including a faulty network card and a broken windows install.

Comment: I would start by installing the most recent driver and software payload from [Intel's driver site](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/36773/Ethernet-Products).  Windows Update should be installing the most recent WHQL driver from Intel, but to rule out anything, download and install it directly from Intel's site.  Once installed, reboot _(if your PC is configured for Fast Boot, shutdown the PC, then turn it back on)_

Comment: Funny, there seems to be no driver specifically for windows10 on their page... Maybe already a bad sign? What driver did windows install then by default? The card was sold with the PC new... weird.
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/50395/Intel-Gigabit-CT-Desktop-Adapter